# Javascript: Functions don't always run correctly, returns inconsistent data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a problem that I'm not too sure how to describe. I am building a web page that has a dynamically generated pdf but it doesn't always load correctly. I think it may have to do with an ajax request but I'm not sure. When the code runs correctly, the result I get in the console is this:

```
s {length: 7, models: Array[7], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
  _byId: Object 
  length: 7 
  models: Array[7]
  __proto__: n
```

When it fails, though, it generates this:

```
s {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
  _byId: Object
  length: 7
  models: Array[7]
  __proto__: n
```

Both have all the data, but only one will run in the foreach I have. I think that it is due to the length being 0 on the first line. The crazy thing is that I have a button that runs re-generates the pdf with new data that calls the same method and it always runs correctly. I don't know what the problem is. Here is some of my code with names shortened:

```
entry : function() {
      if (typeof list === 'undefined') {
        list = new ListCollection();
      }
      list.fetch({success: method1(showPage), data: {}});
    }

method1 : function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'URL' //defined in Routes. does a DB query and returns the data
        }).done(callback);
    },

showPage : function(data) {
      var theModel = new Backbone.Model(JSON.parse(data));
      var view = new Tab.View({model: theModel, 'contentName': 'Name'});
      App.tabDiv.tabContent.show(view);
      var start = $('#date1').val();
      var end = $('#date2').val();
      getData(start, end); 
    },

getData : function(start, end) {
       list.fetch({success: generatePDF(start,end), data: {start: start, end:end});

generatePDF : function(start, end) {
       //lots of stuff but mainly a big foreach on the list then save
}
```

I know that everything works some of the time but other times it almost seems like it skips some step. I have put console messages all throughout and everyone of them runs in order. The button I mentioned just calls the getData method with different start and end dates but it always runs correctly. Thank you for any help.

EDIT: I still need some help with this. A few clarifications: The problem is not with the generatePDF function. Everything in there runs exactly as intended when it receives the correct data. The first two sections that contains the data I get from the console. The extra lines below s are the results I get from opening the arrow for more information about the object. When it runs right, it says "length: 7" in the object details on the main line instead of "length: 0". I think that the error is when it retrieves the data, the ajax request takes too long. I have tries using "async: false" in the ajax but that doesn't solve the issue.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: When you say that it generates a pdf that doesn't always load correctly, do you mean that the browser is redirected to the URL of a PDF to download?  Please explain.

Comment: The issue is that `s` (wherever that is) is not the same in the context that logs `s` and the place where you log out `Object length: 7 models: Array[7] __proto__: n` - somehow it is being overwritten.

Comment: How does the browser download the PDF?

Comment: By generates a pdf I mean that I'm using jsPDF to generate a pdf that is loaded into an iframe. When it runs correctly, all the lines are there for all of the data. When it runs wrong, the pdf loads but only the header shows up.
Sean, I'm not sure what you mean. The extra lines is me pressing the down arrow on the object and those are the extra lines that show up. I ran the the console on the first line of generatePDF. After that, I one use an each function, no more calls.